# How to Install Postgresql Gem on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, chromebook

I have Ubuntu 12.04 Precise installed via crouton on my Asus Chromebook. I have a rails application that requires postgres. When I run "bundle" it fails to install the pg gem. I try installing multiple versions of it independently and it fails. The failure report is below:

> > Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing pg:
> >             ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /home/oscar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150331-16650-11xjo0a.rb extconf.rb checking for
> ```
>
> pg_config... yes Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config You need
>   to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side
>   extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application. You
>   need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side
>   extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
>   checking for libpq-fe.h... no Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=/home/oscar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby
>           --with-pg
>           --without-pg
>           --enable-windows-cross
>           --disable-windows-cross
>           --with-pg-config
>           --without-pg-config
>           --with-pg_config
>           --without-pg_config
>           --with-pg-dir
>           --without-pg-dir
>           --with-pg-include
>           --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
>           --with-pg-lib
>           --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/pg-0.18.1 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /home/oscar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/pg-0.18.1/gem_make.out

I also tried to install it using brew. The files downloaded, and seem to install but when I run "brew upgrade postgresql" it says that postgresql doesn't exits. I am all out of ideas, and I haven't been able to find anyone else with my problem.

Answer (score 32):

As far as I can tell, where it says "You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application" it means that you need to install packages on your system for the gems to work.

So on fedora I had to `yum install postgresql-devel`. Since you're on Ubuntu I think you need to do

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

You may also need `build-essential` so you could run

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev build-essential
```

Comment: This worked at first. I was able to run bundle, but then it got stuck on something saying I needed ruby 2.0.0 or higher. I switched over, but then I have the exact same situation that I had before

Comment: It sounds to me as though you're having trouble with rvm. Is the error the same as above? If not, ask another question on SO.

Comment: I spent about 10 hours trying to get bast this. The two commands above were critical to getting this to work on ubuntu 16.